# How to change div size when add a long text with fixed display

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs, when i added long text on div b with `width: auto` that div cant change own width with own text! as you see the word `Bar` goes to new line!
here my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

div.b{
    width: auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class='a'>Blocked Content Foo</div>
  <div class='b'>Long Text Bar</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to change size of div b which contain **Long Text Bar** when i wrote a long text. thanks

Comment: you can keep your width:auto and add flex-shrink:0

Comment: Please remove  width:auto from 'div.b' selector. and add 'flex:1' on '.flex-container > div'.

Comment: .b{white-space: nowrap;}